# Most elegant way to get 2 variables in string separated by dot in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, vb.net-2010

Suppose I have a string like

```
   Datos = "0000.0100.0200."
```

I want to do something like read string and when I get `.` I know there are two values encoded in the 4 char string so for 0000. I would get

```
Dim a = 00 
Dim b = 00
```

Then for 0100. I would get

```
Dim a = 01 
Dim b = 00
```

Then for 0200. I would get

```
Dim a = 02 
Dim b = 00
```

I have

```
Dim Items() As String = Split(Datos, ".")
For Each oneItem As String In Items
    If Not oneItem .Length < 4 Then
       Dim a = oneItem (0) & oneItem (1)
       Dim b = oneItem (2) & oneItem (3)
       MsgBox(a)
       MsgBox(b)
    End If
Next
```

Is there another more elegant way of getting 2 values from a 4 char string in vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this ..

```
Dim Items() As String = Split(Datos, ".")
For Each oneItem As String In Items
    If oneItem.Length = 4 Then
       Dim a = oneItem.Substring(0,2)
       Dim b = oneItem.Substring(2,2)
       MsgBox(a)
       MsgBox(b)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if your format is a fixed length of `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx`, then I would say that it would be more effective/elegant/maintainable to just use `Substring()` to get the pieces you need, like this:

```
Dim Datos As String = "0000.0100.0200."

Dim a As String = Datos.Substring(0,2)
Dim b As String = Datos.Substring(2,2)

Dim c As String = Datos.Substring(5,2)
Dim d As String = Datos.Substring(7,2)

Dim e As String = Datos.Substring(10,2)
Dim f As String = Datos.Substring(12,2)
```

Comment: In the case the string size is variable? I used split and a for loop

Comment: @cMinor - in that case, yes your approach is fine; as my caveat is no longer true.

Answer (score 1):

why not try linq:

```
Dim expected = Datos.Split("."c).Where(Function(e) e.Length = 4) _
     .SelectMany(Function(n) New String() {n.Substring(0, 2), n.Substring(2, 2)})
```